# how to add 3 attempts in log in

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I would like to know how to add a check in my code that only allows three login attempts per user.

Currently I am using a `do while loop` to iterate over the code three times. Is there another, more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, password FROM acounts WHERE 
username='$username' and password='$password'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  $user = $row['username'];
  $pass = $row['password'];

  $tries =0;
  $limit =3;


 do{
   if($username == "" && $password == ""){

      $message = "The username and password you entered did not match our 
                   records. Please double-check and try again.";
      echo "<script 
      type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('$message');window.location.href 
      = '/juju/login.php';</script>";
      $tries++;


   }else if($username=="admin" &&  $password== $pass){

           header("location:home.php");

   }else if($username==$user &&  $password== $pass){

           header("location: homepatient.php");

   }else if($username != $user || $password != $pass){

            $message = "The username and password you entered did not match 
            our records. Please double-check and try again.";
            echo "<script 
      type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('$message');window.location.href 
      = '/juju/login.php';</script>"; 
     $tries++;
    }

  }while($tries<=3)
```

Comment: do while loops are quite tricky. If used incorrectly, could lead to an indefinite loop For a beginner i would advise that you use a basic forloop. Then incremement when the login is failed. Then check if the number of times(`i`) is 3, then do your logic

Comment: Surely this doesn't work, with any type of loop...? You need to store the attempts in a session and go from there.

Comment: Either save the attempts in a session or database and bind them either to the user OR ip address. If you use an ip address method beaware that people can use vpn's or proxies to bypass it.

Comment: store attempts in `$_SESSION['failed_attempt']` increment it on every attempt to login and check it in `while($tries < = $_SESSION['failed_attempt']);`

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri Don't forget to include a timestamp for the last try, or the user will be locked out for the entire session duration ;)

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden off-course it was just hint for the OP. he have to clear `$_SESSION['failed_attempt']` on success login as well :)